# Synchronizing mutiple processes in C with shared memory

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, locking, shared-memory

I have a program which creates child processes in a for loop with fork(). The child will create other processes as well.

All the processes must increment a count, and the count must be displayed at the end.

To do this I used a simple locking system. The shared memory is of size 2.
There a 2 variable of type sig_tomic_t: the count and a lock.

When a process wants to increment the count it sets the lock to 1, increments the count, then sets the lock to 0. Otherwise, if the lock is 1, then the process sleeps.

Here is the code segment of interest.

```
for(i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {

    if((pid = fork()) < 0) {
        perror("Error fork!");
        exit(2);
    }

    if(*lock == 0) {
        *lock = 1;
        *count = *count  + 1;
        *lock = 0;
    }
    else {
        while(*lock == 1) {
            sleep(1);
        }
    }
 }
```

The problem is that even though I used a simple locking system, the count isn't incremented correctly.

Comment: You can't lock with just atomic variables. Consider a situation where every process gets through the `if (*lock == 0)` command and get switched. Now all of them are going to update the lock to 1, increment the count and update the lock back to 0.

Comment: What happend if the lock is set to 1? Simpli your code waits that the lock is == 0 and then ends...

Comment: You need to use a mutex that you can have a blocking lock call on, so that if another thread/process has the mutex locked your code will wait for its turn.

Also, obviously this is just a simple example. But you should consider for things like this the idea of each process or thread having it's own value of the count and combining them at the end to reduce the amount of time that threads/processes are spinning just waiting for the mutex. In openmp you can do this by instructing it to "reduce" that variable that is modified in a parallel region of code as an example of a possible implementation

Comment: If using gcc thes might be interesting to read: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fsync-Builtins.html#_005f_005fsync-Builtins

Comment: Or you can just use a std::atomic counter and skip the lock entirely.

Comment: `sig_atomic_t` is not a thread-safe atomic. It's for signal-handlers.

Comment: That's because when other processes find lock == 1 they sleep and quit